# Mate as default desktop manager in debian?

Tags: linux, debian, mate

After installing Mate, when I turn on my netbook, Debian doesn't load any windows manager (not even Gnome), after doing some research I understand I have to change the default desktop manager by editing `/etc/X11/default-display-manager` but what do I have to write to run Mate? Also, how do I start Mate manually?

Comment: Which packages did you install? The important package, mate-desktop, is [still in the NEW queue](https://ftp-master.debian.org/new/mate-desktop_1.6.1-1.html).

Comment: I followed [this](http://wiki.mate-desktop.org/download) guide and installed mate-desktop-environment-extra

Comment: What login manager do you use?

Comment: Actually I don't know, I think the default one that comes with Debian since I installed only Mate after formatting.

Comment: Does Mate provide display manager actually? Anyway, it's better to use `alternatives` system than hand-editting files like that. To select `mate` as default _window_ manager you'd execute `update-alternatives --config x-window-manager`. Then you can just `startx` (as user).

Comment: I did **update-alternatives --config x-window-manager** this is the output: **There is only one alternative in link group x-window-manager (providing /usr/bin/x-window-manager): /usr/bin/metacity Nothing to configure.** Mate is installed, no doubt about it, I used it when I installed it. **startx** runs Gnome, I tried to log-out to change to Mate in the login screen but it goes back to text mode.

Comment: Did you follow the instructions here? http://wiki.mate-desktop.org/download

Comment: Yes, I followed that guide.

Comment: Yes, `meatcity` is Gnome's wm; you could try to add `mate` manually, but in general it looks like not configured/broken install.

Comment: Have you tried setting `mdm` in your `/etc/X11/default-display-manager`?

Answer (score 3):

I've installed `lightdm` with

```
apt-get install lightdm
```

which works well and required fewer additional packages and disk space than `gdm3`.

(I could install `gdm3` now but it would still install 130 new packages and would use 230 MB more disk space on my system.)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly try install a display manager. Since you mentioned Gnome, try installing gdm3

```
apt get install gdm3
```

Once installed, on the login screen you should be a drop down list which you can choose which desktop environment

The contents of my /etc/X11/default-display-manager file is

```
/usr/sbin/gdm3
```

Deleting the contents of the file will cause Debian to start up as text only login. So show the graphic display manager, either

1. restore the contents of the file
2. or login as root and run /usr/sbin/gdm3 (or whatever display manager you are running) to show the login window as shown above which you can select MATE as your desktop environment

Comment: I just had to install gdm3, now everything works, thanks a lot man.

Comment: @TadaBanri if the suggestion worked, you should mark the answer as accepted. You should see an empty tick mark near the answer. Accepting the answer makes thewheat gain additional reputation, + other users finding this on the net will know this answer does solve the problem without looking for your comment.